# can I upgrade soft raid0 to raid10 or raid01? and how?

Tags: raid, software-raid

currently status:

4 disk part 200G each, total 800G using raid0

raid0, md0: sda1+sdb1+sdc1+sdd1

and I want to add another disk part sdf1(>800G)

combine with md0 to make a raid10, like

raid1, md1: md0+sdf1

so I can replace the 4disks sd[a-d] later.

but when I tried with a VM,

the filesystem was destroyed afer doing with the following command.

```
mdadm --create --verbose /dev/md1 --level=1 --raid-devices=2 /dev/md0 /dev/sdf1
```

what should I do?

thanks.

Comment: Which filesytem was destroyed? I'd just backup the data, build the new RAID1 and restore the backup on it. You are not trying to create RAID10, but some half-form of RAID01

Comment: Read the manual to understand what commandline tools and their options do. For starters [`man mdadm`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/mdadm) explains that **`--create`** is used  *Create a **new** array*   and you instead would need (possibly among others options and flags)  **`-G, --grow`** to *"**Change** the size or shape of an **active array".***

Answer (score 0):

> ## what should I do?

Ideally: Restore your data from backup!...

If you don't have so one

1. ### Stop everything

   mdadm --stop /dev/md1
2. ### Retrieve loosed datas

   If your `/dev/md0` was LVM, you have to use `gpart`. If it was *`ext4`* you may restore them by using `fsck`, with *superblock backup*. See `man fsck.ext4`
3. ### Re-Create `md1`, but as *degraded* Raid1:

   mdadm --create --verbose /dev/md1 --level=1 --raid-devices=2 missing /dev/sdf1
4. ### Copy datas

   copy your data, from *`md0`* to *`md1`*
5. ### Final step

   Unmount `md0`, move your need (*grub*, *initramfs*...)

   Then add `md0` to `md1`

   ```
   mdadm -a /dev/md1 /dev/md0
   ```

   - Nota you may have to wipe datas on md0 before...

     ```
     dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/md0 count=2048
     ```

Answer (score 0):

@ HBruijn thanks, I'm misunderstanding the command,

and @ Lenniey is right,

this does not upgrade a raid0 to raid10 or raid01,

my filesystem is a private struct, so I need a block-level copy.

but I find a way to get what I want.

```
0) boot into live-cd

1) create a single raid1 md1 with sdf1

2) dd if=/dev/md0 of=/dev/md1

3) stop md0 and md1

4) assemble md1 with sdf1 and update UUID name as same as md0

5) remove sd[a-d]

6) reboot into system
```

confirmed with VM, and will be performed on online system tomorrow.

Comment: Care: meta version >0.98 will overwrite first block of `/dev/md0`! Use `--metadata=0` to avoid this!

Comment: My solution will permit *higher metadata*, Let you *assemble* raid with only 1 disk, so you could copy `md0 -> md1` before re-assembling them!

Comment: Care: Anyway final storage space will become **smaller** then `md0` (because of metadatas)!